# I want to take user input and output it inside GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, tkinter-entry

I want to take user input and output it inside GUI ...
*my code*

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("644x344")

def printSomething():
    label = Label(root, text="???")
    label.grid(row=1, column=2)

ok=Label(root, text="Type your name").grid(row=2,column=1)
entryvalue = StringVar()

entry= Entry(root, textvariable=entryvalue)
entry.grid(row=2, column=2)


button = Button(root, text="Print Me", command=printSomething)
button.grid(row=3, column=2)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing, In order to accept and display the output on the screen you have to use either **Label widget** or **Canvas Text**. Since your code is not updating the Label widget thus I am here doing what you want to do.
First, create a Label widget in the main window,
Get the user input by using.get() method,
print and display the user input.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("644x344")

def printSomething():
    label.config(text=entry.get())


ok=Label(root, text="Type your name")
ok.grid(row=2,column=1)
entryvalue = StringVar()

entry= Entry(root, textvariable=entryvalue)
entry.grid(row=2, column=2)


button = Button(root, text="Print Me", command=printSomething)
button.grid(row=3, column=2)

#Create a Label to print the Name
label= Label(root, text="", font= ('Helvetica 14 bold'), foreground= "red3")
label.grid(row=1, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Here is the Final Output]

Answer (score 0):

To get the text from an input box, use `inputbox.get()`. Also, don't set the `ok` variable to `Label(root, text="Type your name").grid(row=2,column=1)`. This will be set as NoneType, so do

```
ok = Label(root, text="Type your name").grid(row=2,column=1)
ok.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

Here is your code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("644x344")

def printSomething():
    label = Label(root, text=entry.get())
    label.grid(row=1, column=2)

ok=Label(root, text="Type your name")
ok.grid(row=2,column=1)

entryvalue = StringVar()

entry= Entry(root, textvariable=entryvalue)
entry.grid(row=2, column=2)


button = Button(root, text="Print Me", command=printSomething)
button.grid(row=3, column=2)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why did you use `ok = Label(root, text="Type your name").grid(row=2, column=1)`? In that code `ok` will be set to `None` not a `tkinter.Label`. Please move the `.grid(...)` on a new line

Comment: @LizzardOk, I will, but that was copied code from the OP.
\@OP please accept the answer by clicking on the green check mark